# Cannot use list to list curson returned from find in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

i am working with mongodb and i used the method find to retrieve data which is stored in a cursor, when i try to list the result using the function 'result' i can't. Do you have any idea?.It did work with other datas but i don't know why it's not working here. I thank you in advance for your help.
The script is:
`cursor = collection.find({},{ 'type': 1, 'version': 1, 'date': 1, 'identityId': 1, }) list_cursor = list(result) df_subscriber = pd.DataFrame(list_cursor)`
The error i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e060495\Documents\Python Scripts\device_data.py", line 60, in <module>
    list_cursor = list(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1248, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1165, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1052, in __send_message
    response = client._run_operation(
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1330, in _run_operation
    return self._retryable_read(
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1442, in _retryable_read
    with self._socket_from_server(read_pref, server, session) as (sock_info, read_pref):
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1282, in _socket_from_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1217, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(handler=err_handler) as sock_info:
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1407, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(handler=handler)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1520, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(handler=handler)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1378, in connect
    sock_info.authenticate()
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 870, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(creds, self)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 549, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 201, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 767, in command
    return command(
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 166, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "C:\Users\e060495\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 181, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your (current) error has nothing to do with converting the cursor to a list. Rather your error is that the code is not successfully connecting to (specifically authenticating with) the database. The very last line of the error you pasted:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

This is seemingly why your code worked elsewhere but does not currently. Presumably you successfully connected to the previous database but are pointing it elsewhere now.

If you were to change the `find()` to `find_one()` you should see a similar error message reported prior to your call to `list()` (demonstrating that it is an authentication failure).

Your next steps here would be to resolve the connectivity/authentication issues with the database from the client where this code is running.